# How to catch the hardware back button hiding a keyboard on Windows Phone?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, web-applications, back-button

I'm creating a cross-platform webapp using PhoneGap. Cordova allows me to gracefully handle the back-button event and I listen for that event to do the required actions.

Scenario:
On a Windows Phone 8.0/8.1, whenever I click on a text input, the keyboard comes up and I catch the focus event. However, when I click the hardware back button, Cordova back-button event doesn't fire and it's the native back button functionality to dismiss the keyboard that takes place.

Goal: 
I want to somehow catch the dismissal of the keyboard in Windows Phone that occurs after clicking the hardware back button.. After reading through multiple stackoverflow responses and trying, I understand that "blur" event is not supported on IE.

Ask!
I don't want to use the Cordova keyboard plugin because I feel half of the problem is solved using the focus event. Could someone direct me to a graceful solution where I can catch an event when the keyboard is dismissed on Windows Phone using the hardware back button?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried catching the keyup/keydown event but the back button doesn't generate any events when the keyboard is displayed and it's pressed to hide it.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I put a eventlistener to the backbutton, and when the keyboard is up, eventlistener doesnt fire.